# Foreign Characters in Japanese Email

Tags: html

I'm currently working on an issue where Japanese Characters are showing up as **E?**

Ex. もし現在もいらっしゃるよぁ***E??***あれば

I believe my encode/char set is UTF-8, is there a Different one for Japanese?

Comment: What is it supposed to be? It's not that unusual to have letters in Japanese, such as "Plan B" being "プランB".

Comment: Is this in an email as the question title says, if so which email client and what is the code you are using to send it? Or is it in a html webpage, if so what is the html?

Comment: character set are always a pain in the ass to debug cause problems can occur all along the chain, from your database to the client reading the content... A first step would be to identify by when your string is broken...